# Go to fragment on notification click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-notifications

In my project, I am using navigation drawer method. So I am using fragments in java classes. I use Notification manager. When I receive notification, I have to click it would go to notification class. It does not go fragment page. If I use activity, it will have to go activity class. If I use a fragment, it will not intent to fragment class.

Code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,Student_notification.class);
//intent.putExtra("open",1);
PendingIntent pIntent =PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Bitmap bigicon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);

// Build notification
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this).setContentTitle(data.notititle).setContentText("HappySchool")
        .setLargeIcon(bigicon).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo).setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL).build();
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// hide the notification after its selected
noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(data.notificationid), noti);
```

Comment: Once you get the notification go to your activity and call your desire fragment

Comment: @sohan shetty My all classes are fragment because of I use Navigation drawer.It does not intent to Fragment.i can't understand

Comment: @sohanshetty Is it possible?

Comment: You must be intializing your navigation drawer in some acitivyt right

Comment: Homepage has activity

Comment: Then call your HomePage Activity with nofification intent data and then aftter intialiazing the navigation drawer with all fragments check for notification intent data from bundle and call your desire fragment with that intent data

Comment: You should start the `Activity` in which you created navigation drawer. and when you click on the notification, pass a key through intent. And in the activity check which parameter is coming and transact the fragment according to the key.